# Why useSelector is not selecting redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
    (state) => state?.clientAddress?.getAddress
  );

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GET_CLIENT_ADDRESS({}))
    
  }, [dispatch]);




const onSavedAddressSelect = (addressId) => {
    debugger
    if (addressId) {
      const { data: selectedAddress = [] } =  clientAddress ?? {} ;
      console.clear()
      console.log(selectedAddress)
      
      const addressObj = selectedAddress?.filter(
        (addressItem) => addressItem?.value === addressId
      )?.[0];
      setAddress(addressObj);
      setSelectedVenue(addressObj?.value);
    }
    props.drawer.setDrawer({
      open: false,
    });
  };
```

My clientAddress inside onSavedAddressSelect is not getting updated with latest redux state even if I dispatch on first render on useEffect.
Please help.

Comment: can you post the full code.

Comment: @raman here is the full code -  https://pastebin.com/13vWUP45

Answer (score 0):

isn't `clientAddress` is not updated because you call
`dispatch(GET_CLIENT_ADDRESS({}))` with empty object, so it's stays the same? Try to pass there some object with values

Comment: It will handle it with default values which i have handle it in the state. No dependency on that